# What does this combination SCAS and STOS?

Tags: assembly, x86, decompile

I have a simple snippet with several instructions:

```
01:    mov   edi, [ebp+8]
02:    mov   edx, edi
03:    xor   eax, eax
04:    or    ecx, 0FFFFFFFFh
05:    repne scasb
06:    add   ecx, 2
07:    neg   ecx
08:    mov   al, [ebp+0Ch]
09:    mov   edi, edx
10:    rep   stosb
11:    mov   eax, edx
```

I should explain:

> 1.*What is the type of the `[ebp+8]` in line `01` and `[ebp+C]`  in
>   line `08`, respectively.*
>
> 2.*What this code does?*

1. Line `01` is something like `edi = *(ebp+8)`, it stores destination address, not sure. But i can't explain line `08`
2. By following the `intel` manual `SCASB (scan byte string)` i assume what this code does initialize a buffer for the string, repeatedly writes `0` byte `eax` times, then assign `al` to `edi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ebp` points to the stack, which is where function parameters are stored. `ebp+8` is your first parameter, and `ebp+0C` the second one.
- The first parameter is a pointer to a 0-terminated string, and gets loaded into `edi`.
- The `repne scasb` instruction will increment `edi`, and decrement `ecx`, until either `ecx` is zero or `edi` points to a byte that is equal to the one in `al` - 0 in your case, so this scans for the end of a C string.
- Adding 2 to `ecx`, then negating it, will make it equal to the string length. Try it out yourself on paper with an example or two.
- `eax` gets the second pararmeter of the function, from `ebp+0C`.
- The string (the address of the string has been saved in `edx` and is back in `edi`) gets overwritten with the byte in `al` - your second function parameter.

So what this function does is overwrite a null-terminated string of unknown length (parameter 1) with a sequence of identical bytes (parameter 2).

Answer (score 0):

emulating the sequence with powershell

```
cat scasb.ps1
$edx=$edi=$args[0];  $eax=0; $ecx=-1;
while($edi[$ecx--]){}; $ecx+=2;  $ecx=-$ecx;
"length of string using .net method "+$edi.length;
"length of string using repne scasb "+$ecx;
$edi=$edx.tochararray()
while($ecx){$edi[--$ecx]=$args[1]};  $ofs=""; $edx;[string]$edi
```

result

```
powershell -f scasb.ps1 "abracadabra gili gili choo" r
length of string using .net method 26
length of string using repne scasb 26
abracadabra gili gili choo
rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```